Matplotlib 3D 'contour3D' and 'plot_surface' Clash: Contours Not Appearing Above Surface Plot
I'm facing an issue while trying to visualize 3D equipotential surfaces using Matplotlib. Specifically, I'm plotting a surface using plot_surface and then attempting to overlay contour lines using contour3D.
However, no matter what I do, the contour lines seem to be obscured by the surface plot. I've tried various methods, including adjusting the opacity of the surface plot, but this solution is less than ideal as it compromises the clarity of the surface itself.
I attempted to set the zorder attribute to control the drawing order, ensuring the contour lines have a higher zorder value than the surface plot. Unfortunately, this did not produce the desired result, and wasn't sure if its even the right direction i should be taking.
The primary challenge is that the contour lines are not rendering on top of the surface, which makes the visualization less informative and harder to interpret. I need the contours to clearly appear above the surface plot without resorting to transparency tricks.
Here is my full code and the plot produced:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

k_e = 8.99e9
Q = 1e-6
d = 0.2

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 400)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 400)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

c1_pos = np.array([d/2, 0])
c2_pos = np.array([-d/2, 0])

R1 = np.sqrt((X - c1_pos[0])**2 + (Y - c1_pos[1])**2)
R2 = np.sqrt((X - c2_pos[0])**2 + (Y - c2_pos[1])**2)

a = 0.1
V = k_e * Q / (a + R2) - k_e * Q / (a + R1)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom_cmap', ['blue', 'white', 'red'])

vmin = np.min(V)
vmax = np.max(V)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[1, 1.1], wspace=0.2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
back = ax1.pcolormesh(X, Y, V, shading='auto', cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
contour = ax1.contour(X, Y, V, levels=30, colors='black', linewidths=1)

ax1.set_xlabel('X (m)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y (m)')
ax1.set_title('2D Equipotential Lines of a Dipole\n$V = \\frac{k_e Q}{a + r_2} - \\frac{k_e Q}{a + r_1}$')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], projection='3d')

X3D, Y3D = np.meshgrid(x, y)

R1_3D = np.sqrt((X3D - c1_pos[0])**2 + (Y3D - c1_pos[1])**2)
R2_3D = np.sqrt((X3D - c2_pos[0])**2 + (Y3D - c2_pos[1])**2)

V3D = k_e * Q / (a + R2_3D) - k_e * Q / (a + R1_3D)

surf = ax2.plot_surface(X3D, Y3D, V3D, cmap=cmap, edgecolor='none', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, zorder=-1)

contour_levels_3d = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, num=30)
contours_3d = ax2.contour3D(X3D, Y3D, V3D, levels=contour_levels_3d, colors='black', linewidths=1)

ax2.set_xlabel('X (m)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y (m)')
ax2.set_zlabel('Potential (V)')
ax2.set_title('3D Equipotential Surface of a Dipole\n$V = \\frac{k_e Q}{a + r_2} - \\frac{k_e Q}{a + r_1}$')

cbar = fig.colorbar(surf, ax=[ax1, ax2], orientation='vertical', pad=0.05)
cbar.set_label('Potential (V)')

plt.savefig('dipole_potential_plots_combined_with_custom_cmap.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()

Here is the figure rendered
figure rendered

The simplest thing to do would be to place the contours on the bottom plane like this Matplotlib example shows. It's not exactly what you want but might show what you need.

@jared as i grow older i realize i don't always get what i want and so i just move forward and improvise to not waste too much time. but there are some exceptions into how hard i want to get a certain thing done, is it called pride, who knows. thank you for replying anyway.

This could potentially be due to this issue: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles

@tmdavison thank you so much for this conformation.

Using alpha=0.9 in plot_surface helps a lot, but eventually it comes down to Matplotlib algorithmic choices, consider these two, very close views of the same plot:


This is the code (I've changed, restricted the x-y domain)
In [52]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'})
    ...: ax.contour3D(X,Y,V, colors='black', levels=31)
    ...: ax.plot_surface(X,Y,V, color='lightblue', ec='none', cmap='bwr', alpha=0.9, zorder=1)


i decided to go with this thanks for the general idea, at some points of views it is visible I'm not picky so ima going through with it.
